# How to input data in django forms as a list?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to forrward this data as `python list` to django, not as string. How to create list, just to input data separated with commas?

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    list = forms.CharField(label='Input names (separate with commas): ')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own field to make it a comma separated field. This then looks like:

```
# app_name/fields.py

class CommaSeparatedField(forms.CharField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return self.empty_value
        value = str(value).split(',')
        if self.strip:
            value = [s.strip() for s in value]
        return value

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return ', '.join([str(s) for s in value])
```

and then use it in the form with:

```
# app_name/forms.py

from app_name.fields import CommaSeparatedField

class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    list = CommaSeparatedField(label='Input names (separate with commas): ')
```

Django will then return a list of strings in the `form.cleaned_data` in case the form is valid.

Comment: I got an error `AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'CommaSeparatedField'`

Comment: @project.py: that was a typo, it is `list = CommaSeparatedField(...)`, not `list = forms.CommaSeparatedField(...)`.

Comment: I got one more, `'NoneType' object is not iterable`, here `return ', '.join([str(s) for s in value])`?

Comment: @project.py: you can add a `is None` guard.

Comment: @project.py: no, as edited in the answer, we first check `if value is None: return value`.